# Appending new values to pre-existing dictionary keys

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary, key-value

The `set_more` function which is meant to append new values to existing keys is giving me issues and I really can't find why.

```
info = {}
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,info):
        info["Name"] = input("Set:\nDog's name: ")
        info["Age"] = input("Dog's age: ")
        info["Breed"] = input("Dog's breed: ")
    def get_info(self,info):
        self.info = list(info.values())
        infs = []
        for i in range(len(self.info)):
            infs.append(self.info[i])
        print(infs)
        return infs
    def set_more(self,info):
        info.setdefault("Name", []).append(input("Set:\nDog's Name: "))
        info.setdefault("Age", []).append(input("Dog's Age: "))
        info.setdefault("Breed", []).append(input("Dog's Breed: "))  
d = Dog(info)
d.get_info(info)
d.set_more(info)
d.get_info(info)
```

Comment: What issues is it giving you? I don't understand why a Dog would have multiple names, ages and breeds..

Comment: Why are you appending to a string. Why not assign it? Note: A dictionary would be a lot easier

Comment: I think you try to use a dict for class fields which is typcally what is done behind the scene by Python (unless you use \_\_slot\_\_). I would use class attribute `self.name` instead of maintaining an external dict. I would also put the input outside the class or in a specific non \_\_init\_\_ method. And of course as said, if you want to stack the values you'll need to initialize your fields as lists `self.name = [init_name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes.

1. As schwobaseggl mentioned, you need to initialize the values of your dictionaries as lists, so you can append to them later on. You can do this by using brackets: `[input(Dog's age: ")]`
2. Instead of using `setdefault`, just do `info["Field"].append()`. Elaborating on `setdefault`, it only returns the value of the field with the given key. It doesn't allow you to change the dictionary.

Below is the full corrected code.

```
info = {}
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,info):
        info["Name"] = [input("Set:\nDog's name: ")]
        info["Age"] = [input("Dog's age: ")]
        info["Breed"] = [input("Dog's breed: ")]
    def get_info(self,info):
        self.info = list(info.values())
        infs = []
        for i in range(len(self.info)):
            infs.append(self.info[i])
        print(infs)
        return infs
    def set_more(self,info):
        info["Name"].append(input("Set:\nDog's Name: "))
        info["Age"].append(input("Dog's Age: "))
        info["Breed"].append(input("Dog's Breed: "))  
d = Dog(info)
d.get_info(info)
d.set_more(info)
d.get_info(info)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot! I wasn't expecting a response today, much less a great one like this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary approach to your object. Compared to Java or other languages, Python has a very functional and useful dictionary.
`Dog` is of type `dictionary`.

`get_info` gets the input for `name`, `breed`, and `age`. Puts them in a list and returns the list.

`set_info` requires a list input. It assigns the the elements of the list to `Dog`'s elements accordingly.

```
Dog = {}
def get_info():
    info = {}
    info["Name"] = input("Set:\nDog's name: ")
    info["Age"] = input("Dog's age: ")
    info["Breed"] = input("Dog's breed: ")

    print("\n Input Info: \n")
    print(info)
    return info
def set_more(info):
    Dog[info['Name']] = {"Age" : info["Age"], "Breed": info["Breed"]}
   #If you want the Name to be a list item instead of a key:
   #Dog[info['Name']] = {"Name" : info["Name"], "Age" : info["Age"],"Breed": info["Breed"]}

    print("\n Dogs: \n")
    print(Dog)
    print()
    
Dog = {}
    
set_more(get_info())
set_more(get_info())
```

This code does the exact same thing with your code except I am using a dictionary object instead of creating an object.

Note: I wouldn't normally create another function just for assigning but I though you might want both `getter` and `setter` method. If you don't need that, you can simply have one function that gets the input and appends them to `Dog` dictionary as follows:

```
def get_info():
    info["Name"] = input("Set:\nDog's name: ")
    info["Age"] = input("Dog's age: ")
    info["Breed"] = input("Dog's breed: ")
    Dog[info['Name']] = {"Age" : info["Age"], "Breed": info["Breed"]}
    print("\n Input Info: \n")
    print(info)
    return info
```

Every time you called `get_info`, it would ask for input, appends them to `Dog`. That way, the full function would be:

```
info = {}
Dog = {}
def get_info():
    info["Name"] = input("Set:\nDog's name: ")
    info["Age"] = input("Dog's age: ")
    info["Breed"] = input("Dog's breed: ")

    Dog[info['Name']] = {"Age" : info["Age"], "Breed": info["Breed"]}

    print("\n Input Info: \n")
    print(info)
    return info

get_info()
```